# Further explanation on Lipschitz condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lipschitz-functions

I am unable to understand the intent of Lipschitz condition and how to apply it to problems. Primarily the equation

$$\frac{f(x,y_1)-f(x,y_2)}{y_1-y_2}$$

And questions associated with checking whether certain $f(x,y)$ satisfy a Lipschitz condition. Could someone please explain and clarify this for me?

Comment: If you're familiar with the concept of _almost everywhere_, you can think of Lipschitz functions as functions that are almost everywhere differentiable.

If you assume that $f$ is also differentiable, then it's equivalent to having bounded first derivative.

Comment: Besides being almost everywhere differentiable, their derivative is globally bounded in absolute value by a constant.